# Extracting latest googleAppEngine with curl + awk

Tags: curl, awk

I am trying to extract the latest version of google app engine from [their catalog](https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/). To do this I am using curl + awk. I found that the following regex extracts what I need: `/featured\/google_appengine_(.*?)\.zip/g`, but when I try to use it inside:

```
curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/ | awk '/featured\/google_appengine_(.*?)\.zip/'
```

I am getting the full text, not `featured/google_appengine_1.9.17.zip` and when I change it to

```
curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/ | awk '/featured\/google_appengine_(.*?)\.zip{ print $1}/'
```

I get absolutely nothing. Can anyone point me to my mistake?

Comment: `awk` expects whitespace delimited fields - which the text does not appear to have. Perhaps you could try `grep -Eo 'featured\/google_appengine_(.*?)\.zip'` instead?

Comment: @steeldriver thank you. Will it return the latest `google_appengine_` in the list? If so, can you please add it as an answer.

Comment: It will return each match, one per line - grep (and regex in general) has no notion of what 'latest' means. You should really consider using a proper XML parser.

Comment: ... although you could consider hacking something together using `grep -o` followed by `sort -V` and `tail`

Answer (score 1):

This script extract *all* entries of `featured/google_appengine` in alphabetical order:

```
curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/ | awk  -F "featured/google_appengine_" '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print $i }' | awk -F "<" '{print echo "featured/google_appengine_"$1}' | sort
```

E.G.:

```
featured/google_appengine_1.9.18.zip
featured/google_appengine_1.9.19.zip
```

---

If you need the newest version than use this:

```
curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/ | awk  -F "featured/google_appengine_" '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print $i }' | awk -F "<" '{print echo "featured/google_appengine_"$1}' | sort | tail -1
```

E.G.:

```
featured/google_appengine_1.9.19.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the "featured/google_appengine_1.9.17.zip" what you want? Try this quick and dirty solution:
`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/ | awk  -F "featured/google_appengine_" '{print $2}' | awk -F "<" '{print echo "featured/google_appengine_"$1}'`

Comment: Why `print echo`?

Comment: Doesn't work, if there are more than one featured engines.